# How can I close a big hole in a mesh?

Tags: modeling, topology

I have a large hole in a mesh that I'm trying to fill:

[image]

I've been trying an approach like this:

[image]

I'm finding it quite tough, since the number of vertices around the perimeter of the hole don't match a grid.

Is there a better approach to filling a hole like this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select the whole loop around the hole with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> (make sure to delete triangles first). Use a ***Grid Fill*** option (press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type ***Grid Fill***). Then play with its settings.

[image]

Comment: just as a note, grid fill will work with an even number of vrtices

Comment: A combination of this and sculpting seem to do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

I made it this way:

1. Select the whole loop around the hole
2. Shift +D to duplicate
3. Scale the duplicate down (S)
4. Alt + Shift + RMB to add first loop
5. Bridge Edge Loops (space bar search)

and repeate untill the center and then collapse to center

Little work to be done but possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the remesh modifier will close this hole.

Comment: Remesh modifier will close the hole, but will change geometry of the hole mesh depending on its Depth setting, in cases of small organic meshes this could work.

Answer (score 0):

The Mesh seems to be fully triangulated, that means no quad based mesh, no edge loops... so I'd say no, there isn't any other way.

Last time I had that problem where I wanted to "repair" a mesh with bad topology I created some years ago, I rebuild the whole thing since it was faster in the end. Another idea would be to retopologize it by using the well-known methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved like this: go to edit mode, in the Mesh menu, click on "clean-up" and "fill holes"