# Fixing rips on meshes

Tags: modeling, mesh

Okay, so I'm a newbie at blender and I'm getting to know the modeling/ sculpting aspects of the program. However, I have run into a major problem, when sculpting, there will be rips created on the surface of my mesh. It is easy enough to simply merge points together or fill, but when I'm creating a extremely high ploy count image like shown below and have massive rips, it takes for ever to correct including the wait time for my computer to load every vertex on every poly.[image: Of course this is an extreme case I was sculpting with symmetry on the other side and didn't notice, but you get the point]

I was wondering if there is a better way of preventing or easily fixing this problem.

Comment: Could you include more info as to what exactly happens when sculpting ? Where are those rips on the screenshot ? Holes in mesh could appear while sculpting because of double vertices (select all > Remove Doubles) or unconnected vertices etc. Depending on case solutions differ.

Comment: @MrZak most of the time it is just small triangle holes are created in the mesh, there wasn't any like that at the moment I decided to ask, so I used a more extreme case that I hadn't fixed yet(the enormous gapping hole in the center of the screen) that happened because I was sculpting with symmetry and a hole was created on the other side which got expanded when I continued sculpting. I remove doubles every once and a while, it doesn't help that much.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52661/how-can-i-close-a-big-hole-in-a-mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the [fill holes](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/cleanup.html) mesh cleanup tool? Select the area containing holes and go to Mesh ‣ Clean up ‣ Fill Holes.

You might also want to check out the limited dissolve tool based on your screen shot.

Comment: Thank you, you are my savior(limit dissolve really helped too)