# how to close geometry automatically?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, geometry

I did a mistake while modelling this object, i duplicated all parts but i forgot to fill the back faces before duplicating it. I would like to know if theres a way to fill all faces without having to click vertex by vertex and filling it

[image]

Comment: Try selecting the whole inner loop of edges with Alt+Left Click, then select `Face > Grid Fill` from the menu at the top of the Viewport

Comment: @ChristopherBennett it worked! thanksaq a lot Chris!!

Comment: Here, I'll put that as an answer so this wont be in the unanswered list.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52661/how-can-i-close-a-big-hole-in-a-mesh/52663#52663

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the whole inner loop of edges using alt+left click, then select `Face > Grid Fill` from the menu at the top of the Viewport